# Drawing lines between clicks draws from top left corner

Tags: java, drawing, processing

I'm currently trying to create a program using processing that draws lines from all mouseclicks to new mouseclicks.
As a side it also should save the clicks in a two-dimensional array.

```
    public void setup() {
        size(500,500);
    }

    int clickcount = 0;
    int storedclicks = 10000;
    int[] mouseclickX = new int [storedclicks];
    int[] mouseclickY = new int [storedclicks];

    public void draw() {
        background(80);
        drawing();
    }

    public void mousePressed() {

        if(clickcount >= storedclicks) {
            clickcount = 0;
        }

        mouseclickX[clickcount] = mouseX;
        mouseclickY[clickcount] = mouseY;
        clickcount++;

    }

    public void drawing() {
        beginShape(LINES);
            for (int i = 0; i < storedclicks; i++) {
                vertex(mouseclickX[i], mouseclickY[i]);
            }
            endShape();
    }
}
```

Something works with the code I have now, but something doesn't add up for me. As it is now, on first click I get a line from the upper left corner, next click that line disappears and I get a new line from the ending point of that line and the first line disappears.

Next click a new line from the corner to clicking point comes (line nr. 2 still present). And then it just continues.

I figured if I changed the `storeclicks` to a number like 5, it doesn't do the from corner thing, just a new line from every previous click position.

It sounds a little confusing, so here's a picture to help (after 3 clicks):
[image]

Comment: For a better understanding of your problem (or for more precision) you might want to add the order of clicks to your image. I have an assumption (which my answer is based upon) but it would help make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

I'd use a lifo ring buffer (you could simulate it with a linked list) or similar to store the clicks, that way you don't have to check `storedclicks` separately and it should make drawing easier since the head of the buffer moves when you remove elements from the front.

Additionally I'd only draw lines if there are at least two points in the list/buffer.

Third, to prevent synchronization issues (updating only x or y) I'd use a list/buffer/array of `Point` objects (make your own or use `java.awt.Point`) rather than two separate x and y arrays.

As for your drawing code you should loop over the stored points rather than all elements (most of which might be empty), i.e. like this:

When using your code:

```
if( clickcount > 1 ) {
  for (int i = 0; i < clickcount ; i++) {
     vertex(mouseclickX[i], mouseclickY[i]);
  }
}
```

When using a list/ring buffer as well as `Point` objects:

```
if( list.size() > 1 ) {
  for (Point clickpos : list ) {
     vertex(clickpos.x, clickpos.y);
  }
}
```

Finally, if processing is similar to OpenGL (I don't know processing) the shape type `LINES` would draw a line between two vertices, i.e. every uneven vertex is a line start and every even vertex is a line end. What you probably want is something like `LINE_STRIP` (don't know the name or whether it exists in processing) which makes the renderer draw lines between all vertices (i.e. from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2 etc.)

**Edit:**

As an explanation for the situation in the image you posted, I assume the clicks are ordered from right to left (indices 0, 1, 2). If that's the case then I'd explain it like this (see above for more info):

- The first line is drawn between points 0 and 1, which is ok.
- The second line is drawn between points 2 and 3 (see paragraph about the loop as well as `LINES` resp. line strips), which is not what you want.
- The third line (if `storedclicks > 5`) will be drawn between points 4 and 5, which is a point since both vertices have the coordinates 0/0.
- The above bulletpoint is repeated for all following lines (again see the paragraph about the loop).

As you can see there are two problems:

- You'd want to draw lines between 0 and 1  and between 1 and 2 which is why I suggested a line strip (if that exists in processing, otherwise you'd have to reuse the last point).
- You'd want to stop at index 2, i.e. ignore all indices starting from 3, which is why I mentioned not using `storedclicks` in the loop condition).

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's happening in your sketch, look to [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html).

This code:

```
beginShape(LINES);
vertex(30, 20);
vertex(85, 20);
vertex(85, 75);
vertex(30, 75);
endShape();
```

Generates this image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [processing.org](https://www.processing.org/reference/images/beginShape_2.png))</sub>

So, that's why you're getting gaps where your line segments aren't drawn. Instead of using `LINES`, you probably want to use the no-args `beginShape()` function along with the `endShape(CLOSE)` function:

[image]
<sub>(source: [processing.org](https://www.processing.org/reference/images/beginShape_4.png))</sub>

```
noFill();
beginShape();
vertex(30, 20);
vertex(85, 20);
vertex(85, 75);
vertex(30, 75);
endShape(CLOSE);
```

As for why you're getting a point at 0,0: keep in mind that int arrays are initialized to contain all zeroes by default. So when you loop through your entire array, you end up drawing a bunch of points at 0,0. Instead, you probably want a separate variable that keeps track of the total number of clicks (which you stop updating when you reach the maximum number of clicks you want to hold).

> As a side it also should save the clicks in a two-dimensional array.

Note that you aren't storing the clicks in a two-dimensional array. You're storing them in two one-dimensional arrays, also known as parallel arrays. This is generally a bad design. Instead, consider using Processing's `PVector` class along with an `ArrayList` instead of an array. That way you can keep track of how many valid clicks you have without needing the separate variable I mentioned above.

Putting it all together, it might look something like this:

```
ArrayList<PVector> clicks = new ArrayList<PVector>();

public void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

public void draw() {
  background(80);
  drawing();
}

public void mousePressed() {
  clicks.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
  if(clicks.size() > 5){
    clicks.remove(0);
  }
}

public void drawing() {
  noFill();
  beginShape();
  for(PVector v : clicks){
    vertex(v.x, v.y);
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

> draws lines from all mouseclicks to new mouseclicks.

If instead of a closed polygon, you want something like a spider web that connects every point to every other point, then you just have to loop through each click and draw the connecting lines:

```
public void drawing() {
  for (PVector v1 : clicks) {
    for (PVector v2 : clicks) {
      line(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the existing great answers, here's a hacky approach that simply takes advantage of not clearing the background:

```
int lastClickX = -1;
int lastClickY = -1;
void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  background(80);
}
void draw(){}
void mouseReleased(){
  if(lastClickX >= 0 && lastClickY >= 0)  line(mouseX,mouseY,lastClickX,lastClickY);
  lastClickX = mouseX;
  lastClickY = mouseY;
}
```

You can run this as demo bellow:

```js
var lastClickX = -1;
var lastClickY = -1;
function setup(){
  createCanvas(500,500);
  background(80);
}
function draw(){}
function mouseReleased(){
  if(lastClickX >= 0 && lastClickY >= 0)  line(mouseX,mouseY,lastClickX,lastClickY);
  lastClickX = mouseX;
  lastClickY = mouseY;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.17/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Bare in mind, although this method doesn't store position, it simply takes advantage of not clearing the screen, which isn't the most flexible of options.